# How do you make <a> links side by side in the header?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, header

I want to make the  links side to side in the header. I need help with the CSS part.

```
<body>
<nav>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="index.php"><umg src="spaceship.png" alt="blogs logo"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="discover.php">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.php">Find Blogs</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

That is my HTML code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
nav .wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul{
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should contain http
For example
href="https://classroom.udacity.com/nanodegrees/nd004-1mac-v2/dashboard/overview"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this??

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background-color:black;
  padding-top:10px;
  }
  
 .wrapper > a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  }
  
a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline
  }
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="index.php"><img src="spaceship.png" alt="blogs logo"></a>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="discover.php">About us</a>
<a href="blog.php">Find Blogs</a>
<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
<a href="login.php">Login</a>

</div>
</nav>
```